# Critique follow-ups

Tags: discussion, critique

> This policy discussion is now out of date. [Critique questions are off-topic on Writers.SE](https://writers.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/878/does-writers-se-accept-critique-requests). Please look for more recent posts on this topic.

After posting a critique, what is the proper ettiquite for asking for further assistance? I recently posted a critique and got some good feedback. Is it alright to ask "Is this better"? Should I do so in an edit to the same question, or a separate one? What if it's a second excerpt rather than an edit of the first?

Answer (score 3):

Normally the old critique question is updated with markings where the edited version starts (and ends).

If this is getting too long and/or it's a complete rewrite which has not much in common with the old one, I suggest to ask a new question with a link to the old one. Just try that. If the community doesn't like it, we can close it and you can still add your new version to the old question.

Be aware that the new question still has to follow the guideline for critique questions, no matter if it is a follow-up or not.