# How should Writers encourage broad (but not too broad) answers?

Tags: discussion, answers

One difficulty for the Writers Stack Exchange is that writing questions tend to be more subjective (requiring greater length for a good answer) and often address a specific problem the asker has (leaning toward being "too localized", which is part of the discussion in ["Critiques considered harmful?"](https://writers.meta.stackexchange.com/q/878/5232)).

As Monica Cellio commented in "Critiques considered harmful?", some people «I tend to notice giving broader answers that would be useful to people other than the OP; how do we "bottle that" and get more of that from others?». While this issue is *virtually essential* for critique questions (which are likely to become off-topic in part *because* answers tend to be excessively localized, matching the localization of the question), it seems to apply more generally.

[Neil Fein's answer](https://writers.stackexchange.com/a/12735/5232) to ["Simple rules for separating paragraphs in books?"](https://writers.stackexchange.com/q/12734/5232) seems like a decent example of an answer that broadens the scope of the question without being too broad or too long.

So how do we "bottle that"?

---

Broad answers have the danger of not clearly answering the specific question in a manner useful to the asker or to a site visitor. Concise and more focused answers are often useful even though less complete. Organization (including summaries and the use of headers) helps, but at some point a general answer stops addressing well the specific question. (The 30,000 character post length limit provides *some* constraint, though I suspect just the effort required for a long post that would be upvoted might be a stronger constraint. Attracting upvotes tends to require the post be readable and interesting even if not actually answering the question well.)

Answer (score 1):

> One difficulty for the Writers Stack Exchange is that writing questions tend to be more subjective

Aside from questions that depend on a specific style manual, or very basic technical writing questions, or questions about certain well-established techniques (i.e., the three-act structure in screenwriting), most questions here *are* extremely subjective.

The community here is small, but is also very good at providing good answers to... not-so-good questions. High-rep users here have learned how to write at length on questions that cut to the core well and address the underlying problem.

> [Neil Fein's answer](https://writers.stackexchange.com/a/12735/5232) to ["Simple rules for separating paragraphs in books?"](https://writers.stackexchange.com/q/12734/5232) seems like a decent example of an answer that broadens the scope of the question without being too broad or too long.
>
> So how do we "bottle that"?

In this case, the question itself had several things that allowed this. The title itself, **Simple rules for separating paragraphs in books?**, asked for a broader answer. (It could easily have been, "How do I decide when to separate paragraphs?")

I'd suggest that the answer to how to keep this going is to just keep asking good questions and answering them. The content on a Q&A site sets the tone, and new users pick up on that when they ask and answer questions of their own.

Let's all continue to set a good example and this phenomenon of answering questions with a larger audience in mind should continue naturally.

Comment: We should also consider making edits to the question that *do not harm the question* but make it a little easier to write a better answer (like the title change you mentioned here).