# Where can I get a critique of my work?

Tags: discussion, critique

[Questions asking for critiques are off topic](https://writers.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/878/critiques-considered-harmful). We don't want to leave people high and dry, so having a list of places to get a general critique would be helpful. These sites can also do more than we ever could do in a Q&A format — sometimes a draft needs extended discussion, something not possible here.

Please feel free to add to this. It's Community Wiki to encourage participation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### On Writing Stack Exchange

While critiques are off-topic on the main site, they are welcome in chat ([Beta Reviewers/Reviewing](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115415/beta-reviewers-reviewing)) for those who have [20 reputation](https://writing.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/chat).

### Online critique sites

**[Fictionpress](http://www.fictionpress.com/)** allows anyone to upload stories, read those stories, and comment.  As the site is wide open, the quality of comments varies wildly, along with the quality of stories. It's easy to use and has a large user-base. *[source](https://writers.stackexchange.com/a/907/26)*

**[Critters Workshop](http://www.critters.org/)** is an online critique group. (You have to give about 3 critiques per month to have your stories critiqued).  It is also designed to encourage useful, constructive, and in-depth feedback. It used to be science-fiction/fantasy/horror only; those parts of the site have been around longer than the the other genre sections. *[source](https://writers.stackexchange.com/a/907/26)*, *[source](https://writers.stackexchange.com/a/1650/26)*

**[Critique Circle](http://www.critiquecircle.com/)** is members-only: Work put up for critique [isn't visible unless you're a member](http://www.critiquecircle.com/faq.asp?all=&cat=0#140), so it's not "published online". *[source](https://writers.stackexchange.com/a/913/26)*

### Sites with a critique section:

**[Scribophile](http://www.scribophile.com/)** has tools for helping with structuring critiques that are quite helpful. You earn points to make submissions depending on the length of critiques and whether they are appreciated by other site members. Critiques are visible only to members. *[source](https://writers.stackexchange.com/a/1653/26)* May have a heavy focus on scifi.

**[The Erotica Readers and Writers Association](http://www.erotica-readers.com/)**. They host a "Storytime" mailing list where you can post your work for critique. *[source](https://writers.stackexchange.com/a/920/26)*

### Subreddits:

**[r/writing](http://www.reddit.com/r/writing)** has a weekly critique thread.

**[r/scifiwriting](http://www.reddit.com/r/scifiwriting)** allows general critiques. It's a small subreddit but looks pretty active.

**[r/DestructiveReaders](http://www.reddit.com/r/DestructiveReaders)** encourages brutal critiques.