# What to do after accepting someone's critical advice on sampled work on SE?

Tags: discussion

I have read very small whispers and rumors of writers able to post samples of their own work on SE and asking questions regarding improving specific aspects of their work. This sounds great, and if true I wish to get involved, mostly on receiving critical suggestions for my own practice writing, because I am very green.

However let us assume that I have already submitted my sample work, and I accept to take critical advice to heart to change and rework, and I actually rework the work. Now what? Do I re-post the edited work to check if the edits were made in the suggested direction? Shall I rinse in repeat to master the specific aspect of writing on SE again? Or do I write another question?

What to do after accepting someone's critical advice on sampled work on SE?

Answer (score 2):

Critique questions are [off-topic here](https://writers.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/878/does-writers-se-accept-critique-requests/879#879). It's okay to use your work as an example of a question you have, but there has to be a specific, answerable question.

If you ask a question and the answers you get here result in you revising your work, whether you follow up or not depends on whether you have additional questions to ask about it.

Comment: I am under the assumption that re-asking the same question after revising the work is off topic. Is this correct?

Comment: Remember, it's the question that matters. If it was the same question being asked, adding nothing new, we'd probably close it as a duplicate.

Comment: I think the main problem with critique questions was not "too broad" (or "opinion-based"/unanswerable) but "too localized".