# Is there a place for critiquing book proposals within stack exchange?

Tags: discussion, critique, answers, editing, reviews

Is there a place in Stack Exchange where you can share an excerpt of a story or proposed book and receive feedback?

Comment: You can try the [Writers' chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/168/the-overlook-hotel)

Answer (score 3):

No, there's currently no site (or other formal process) where you can get critiques on Stack Exchange. The closest I know of is the mid-week group chat at writers where we freewrite and discuss, but that's not on the main site.

This site has decided that critique questions are off-topic, because they're very difficult to make work within a Q&A framework; we tried them and only later [decided against having critiques here](https://writers.meta.stackexchange.com/a/879/26).

You're not the first to ask about this, and it seems other people are also having problems getting critiques to work on Stack Exchange. There was a [critique site proposal at area 51](https://writers.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1079/26) (our site for creating new Stack Exchange sites) but it didn't take off.