# If the answers ask me to put my work, would this make my question becomes a critique request?

Tags: discussion, critique

In the [In a formal writing, does having a paragraph rewritten by another person make the style change noticablely?](https://writers.stackexchange.com/q/19540/11428) question, I have tried to ask a general question, to better serve the future visitors. However, most answerers say that it is hard to know if they can't read my work. I'm of course happy to give them the link, but would this make the question become a critique request?

I have only skimmed the answers in [Does Writers.SE accept critique requests?](https://writers.meta.stackexchange.com/q/878/11428), but it seems that the consensus answer is no. But it doesn't mention about what if the answerers explicitly say that they need to read my work to evaluate.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're asking a general question about mixing styles, not a critique question, which is the right approach.  Your question could be enhanced by including one before-and-after example, to help people see the magnitude of the change, but I don't think posting the whole thing will help all that much.

The example would help people understand the magnitude of the change.  From there, people can assess what it would be like to read a bunch of text in the "before" style with an "after"-style paragraph interspersed.  That should allow people to answer your question.

I notice that some answers are addressing whether you should use formal style, but I understand your question to be about the *mixing*, not about the choice of formal/informal.  If my impression is correct, you might want to comment to that effect on those answers.  If my impression is incorrect, you might want to clarify that in the question.

Comment: surely that after converting from informal tone to formal tone, the style will be changed. What I mean is after the converting, does my already formal paragraph mix well with the other new formal paragraphs? So I think giving the before and after paragraph will not help much. They need to see at least one of mine and one of my friend in the final draft to see if the mixing is good or not. And that will make my question becomes a critique request, I'm afraid

Comment: @Ooker that would work too.  I suggested "before and after" so people could see how big the changes are; presumably your other paragraphs are like the "before" version.  But one of yours and then the revised one would convey that, too.  Your question is open and has answers (one of which you accepted), so maybe you don't need to make any changes -- totally up to you.