# Writing for advertising - on or off topic?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

If I were looking for feedback on any wording I'd done for an advertising campaign, would this forum be a suitable place to ask it? Or is it more intended for writing for fiction?

Answer (score 3):

This site isn't just for fiction; we welcome questions about all types of writing.  If you browse the tags you'll see technical writing, scientific writing, and journalism, among others.

However, it sounds like you're looking for a critique, which is [off-topic](https://writers.meta.stackexchange.com/a/879/1993).  You're welcome to ask questions about advertising writing, and to use *examples* from your own work, but the question you ask needs to be a question about some writing technique or consideration, not about feedback.

I know this can sound like hair-splitting.  Please read the post I linked to, which explains it in a little more detail.