# Can we change the "writing critique" close reason to say Writing.SE instead of Writers.SE?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, close-reasons, site-name

Currently the custom off-topic close reason about us not accepting writing critiques says:

> While questions that use your writing to illustrate a point in the question are fine, requests for writing critiques are off-topic here. For more information, see [Does Writers.SE accept critique requests?](https://writers.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/878/does-writers-se-accept-critique-requests)

And the link address is (emphasis mine):

> [meta]/questions/878/does-**writers-se**-accept-critique-requests

The link should be changed to be:

> `[Does Writing.SE accept critique requests?](https://writers.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/878)`

or just

> `https://writers.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/878`

if the automatic boxing of links works in close reasons, as [This site is now Writing](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1463/23159). That way we won't have to adapt the close reason in cases where we change the title of the referenced question.

Alternatively we could find a different neutral phrasing. All the other links in the custom close reasons still point to "*writers*.stackexchange.", but they have texts like "this meta answer", "what to write" and "rephrasing a sentence or passage". Maybe we could simply change the text in the critique close reason to "For more information, see [our critique policy]."

Comment: Changing the close reason text from Writers SE to *something else* seems like a good idea.

Comment: The link should also change to say "**writing**.meta.stackexchange.com" :)

Comment: @doppelgreener That would be nice, which is why I pointed out that the other links also still point there, but it is not really relevant. Very few people will check out that link before clicking it and they are simply redirected. The thing that *most* people read is what I think is the bigger problem. And as I don't know how much work it is to change all custom close reasons I want to focus on that problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The "writing critique" close reason has now been updated to say Writing SE instead of Writers SE.

Unfortunately (or not, really), we're stuck with the one we had on old questions, but anything put on hold with that reason from now on should say Writing.